# Wicket AjaxFallbackLink behaviour

Tags: wicket

I use the AjaxFallbackLink component for an Ajax link. When I mouse-over the link, the URL looks something like ./myPage?1-1.ILinkListener-xxx. And when I actually click the link, however, the Ajax request looks something like: ./myPage?1-1.IBehaviorListener-xxx.

It seems that Wicket JavaScript has somehow changed the URL from ILinkListener to IBehaviorListener. Wonder if it is so, and why is that?

Sometimes in certain circumstances ILinkListener in the URL is not changed to IBehaviorListener when the request is sent out by the browser, which causes NullPointerException as parameter AjaxRequestTarget target in the callback function is null. I haven't been able to reproduce this. Just wonder what browser settings could cause this to happen. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those URLs are correct.

The first **static link** address '*./myPage?1-1.ILinkListener-xxx.*' is a generic link address for a link in case it invokes a URL and process the link.

The second **AJAX link** address './myPage?1-1.IBehaviorListener-xxx' is a generic JavaScript/AJAX behavior. In case when JavaScript is working, the JavaScript is attached as an onclick event (see jQuery click() function at https://api.jquery.com/click/) and it processes the link, then it shouldn't continue to process the URL from HREF attribute.

So far you would expect to request only one of those URLs when the link is clicked. But in case of AjaxFallbackLink when there is no AJAX then onClick(AjaxRequestTarget) is invoked as onClick(null), it causes NPE if you rely on existing AjaxRequestTarget object, but there is no guarantee for that.

The last part of your question is not clear when it is not possible to reproduce. But Wicket uses jQuery, if you add jQuery library into the HTML, there is a possible conflict of versions.

There are some more detail on a similar issue at http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/AjaxFallbackLink-s-onClick-with-null-AjaxRequestTarget-migrating-1-4-to-6-td4652143.html

Comment: Thanks Martin. As you mentioned, there could be no AJAX in case of AjaxFallbackLink. And this is exactly the last part of my question, how to make this happen in a modern browser, i.e., no AJAX but JavaScript enabled? Just in case you know how.

Comment: It could be caused by different issues, e.g. override or duplicate reference to jQuery (JS library) or replace onClick function on your link if you add another behavior or if you stop the JS event propragation or something like that. I would check: 1) Is there only one jQuery in the HTML header, 2) Is there NO other behavior on your link?, 3) Is there ONLY one onClick event attached in the HTML header to your link? 4) Is there NO generic onclick event attached to all HTML links?

Comment: In my case, Ajax behaviour is expected and indeed it works as expected in all my browsers; but for some users the generic link is used instead according to the Tomcat access logs. So the only difference is at the browser's side. I'm now trying to disable Ajax but with JavaScript kept enabled. I'll get back on this later.

Comment: Ok, after reading your comment: if jQuery hasn't been loaded (e.g. network issue), the simple HTML link is used instead.

Comment: I see. That sounds like the case. Thanks Martin.